# Get object property name with corresponding value

Tags: javascript

I have a field object that can contain only one of different properties with an id as a value.

```
const Field = {
  // Field can contain
  property1Id: 'someId',
  // Or 
  property2Id: 'someOtherId',
  // Or
  property3Id: '...'
  //...
};
```

I want to return the property name and it's value. The following works fine but feels a bit long. Anyway to reduce it / be more efficient.

```
const propertyName = Field.property1Id
  ? 'Property 1'
  : someObject.property2Id
  ? 'Property 2'
  : someObject.property3Id
  ? 'Property 3'
  : 'Other';

const id = Field.object1Id
  ? Field.property1Id
  : Field.property2Id
  ? Field.property2Id
  : Field.property3Id
  ? Field.property3Id
  : null;

console.log(propertyName, id)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `let k = Object.keys(Field)[0]; console.log(k, Field[k]);`…?

Comment: Or `const [[propertyName, id]] = Object.entries(Field);` ... I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it atm.

Comment: This does not quite do the same as it does not change the property name.  My `propertyId1` is not quite readable and I need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean, every property name with property value is returned :)

```js
const Field = {
   // Field can contain
  property1Id: 'someId',
  // Or 
  property2Id: 'someOtherId',
  // Or
  property3Id: '...'
  //...
}

let entries = Object.entries(Field);
entries.forEach(entry => {
  console.log(entry)
})
```

Comment: As I said above, I also need to change the property name.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach

```
const Field = {
  // Field can contain
  property1Id: 'someId',
  // Or 
  property2Id: 'someOtherId',
  // Or
  property3Id: '...'
  //...
};

let i = 0;
for (const property in Field) {
  i++
  console.log('Property ' + i, Field[property]);
}

Output: 
"Property 1" "someId"
"Property 2" "someOtherId"
"Property 3" "..."
```

Comment: Same comment as above, I also need to change the property name.

Comment: Please take a look, changed the property name as you mentioned above. @achilleb

Comment: This doesn't work either. The names I used here are some examples. The real names don't have number in them. And I need to change them based on conditions.

Comment: What condition you are looking for? You can add any condition before console.log